# PHP unable to get parameter from URL

Tags: php, get

for some strange reason I'm unable to get GET value from URL

```
$URL=localhost/supplies/cartridges/?Brand%5B%5D=HP
```

Here's I'm going to check get but this return an empty array

```
 public function getGetparameters(){
    $get=$_GET;
    var_dump($get);
}
```

var_dump returns next:

```
array(0) { }
```

I cannot understand why as this

```
$URL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parsedURL=parse_url($URL);
    $URLQ=$parsedURL['query'];
    echo $URLQ;
```

returns

```
Brand%5B%5D=HP
```

Unfortunatelly I need to use get Parameters so I've stuck a bit :(

Code that generating get:

```
<form action="" method="get"><h4>Brand:</h4><div class="input-control checkbox">
              <label>
              <input name="Brand[]" type="checkbox" value="HP">
                <span class="check"></span>HP</label>
              </div>
               <button type="submit" class="bg-darkCobalt" style="box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000000; color: #ffffff"><i class="icon-list on-left fg-white"></i>Filter</button>
    </form>
```

I'd like simply to replace Brand[] to Brand but later I will add some more brands and I need to maintain those simultaneously, so this is not solution

As I was asked to paste whole class here's it is. PS: Sorry for russian/ukrainian characters :)

```
class CatalogHandler extends generalRenderer{
public function getCatalogName(){
    $URL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parsedURL=parse_url($URL);
    $URLPath=$parsedURL['path'];
    $array = explode('/',$URLPath);
    $rev = array_reverse($array);
    $catalog = $rev[1];
    return $catalog;
}
public function getGetparameters(){
    var_dump($_GET);
}



public function renderTitleAndMetaAndSetHeader($newSQL){
    while($row=$this->fetchArray($newSQL)){
        echo "<title>".$row['Title']." ".$this->setSuffix."</title>
             <meta name='description' content='".$row['Desc']."'/>
             <meta name='keywords' content='".$row['KeyWord']."'/>
        ";
        $this->setHeader($row['Title']);
    }
}
public function getCatalogJS($path,$catalogname){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".$path."js/".$catalogname.".js'></script>";
}
public function getFilters($newSQL,$SQL){
    echo "<div class='grid'> <div class='row'><div class='span3 padding10 border'>
                    <form action='' method='get'>";
    $this->getBrands($newSQL);
    $this->getTypes($SQL);
    echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>
    <button type='submit' class='bg-darkCobalt' style='box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000000; color: #ffffff'><i class='icon-list on-left fg-white'></i>Фильтровать</button>
    </form>
    </div>";
}
public function checkedBrandAndFilter($row){
    if(!empty($_GET['Brand'])&&in_array('HP',$_GET['Brand'])){
        echo "checked='checked'";
    }
    else{
        echo "";
    }
}
public function checkedTypeAndFilter($row){
    if(!empty($_GET['Type'])&&in_array($row['Type'],$_GET['Type'])){
        echo "checked='checked'";
    }
    else{
        echo "";
    }
}
public function getBrands($newSQL){
    echo "<h4>Brand:</h4>";
    while($row=$this->fetchArray($newSQL)){
        echo "<div class='input-control checkbox'>
              <label>
              <input name='Brand[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['Brand']."'";
               if(!empty($_GET['Brand'])&&in_array('HP',$_GET['Brand'])){
                    echo "checked='checked'";
               }
                else{
                    echo "checked=''";
                    echo $_GET['Brand'];
                }
              echo "/>
                <span class='check'></span>".$row['Brand']."</label>
              </div>
        ";
    }
}
public function getTypes($SQL){
    echo "<h4>Тип:</h4>";
    while($row=$this->fetchArray($SQL)){
        echo "<div class='input-control checkbox'>
              <label>
              <input name='Type[]' type='checkbox' value='".$row['Type']."'
               ".$this->checkedTypeAndFilter($row)."/>
                <span class='check'></span>".$row['Type']."</label>
              </div>
        ";
    }
}
public function getProductNameModelAndLink($row){
    echo "<a href='".$row['Brand']."-".$row['Model']."'><h4>".$row['Brand']." ".$row['Model']."</h4></a>";
}
public function getProductIMG($row){
    echo "<a href='".$row['Brand']."-".$row['Model']."'>
                <img class='span2 shadow' src='".$row['IMGPath']."' alt='".$row['Brand']." ".$row['Model']." купить и провести сервисное обслуживание в Житомире и области'/>
          </a>";
}
public function getBrand4Tech($row){
    if(isset($row['Brand'])){
    echo "Производитель: ".$row['Brand']." / ";
    }
    else{
    }
}
public function getModel4Tech($row){
    if(isset($row['Model'])){
        echo "Модель: ".$row['Model']." / ";
    }
    else{
    }
}
public function getType4Tech($row){
    if(isset($row['Type'])){
        echo "Тип: ".$row['Type']." / ";
    }
    else{
    }
}
public function getCode4Tech($row){
    if(isset($row['Code'])){
        echo "Код: ".$row['Code']." / ";
    }
    else{
    }
}
public function getProductTechInfo($row){
    $this->getBrand4Tech($row);
    $this->getModel4Tech($row);
    $this->getType4Tech($row);
    $this->getCode4Tech($row);
}
public function renderProducts($SQL,$catalogname){
    echo "<div class='span9'>";
    while($row=$this->fetchArray($SQL)){
        $this->getProductNameModelAndLink($row);
        $this->getProductIMG($row);
        echo "<div class='span7'>";
        $this->getProductTechInfo($row);
        $this->renderPrice($row);
        $this->getBuyButton($catalogname,$row);
        $this->renderStock($row);
        echo "</div>";

                    echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
    }
    echo "</div></div></div>";
}
}
```

And this how it is used:

```
<?php
include('CatalogHandler.php');
include('DBconfig.php');

$config = new DBconfig('localhost','setuser','a11235813b','setua');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','setuser','a11235813b','setua');
$catalog = new CatalogHandler($config);
$catalogname=$catalog->getCatalogName();

$catalog->openConnection();
$query="SELECT * FROM metaandtitlecatalogs WHERE Cat='".$catalogname."'";
$query4brands="SELECT DISTINCT(Brand) AS Brand FROM ".$catalogname;
$query4types="SELECT DISTINCT(Type) AS Type FROM ".$catalogname;
$query4catalog="SELECT * FROM ".$catalogname;

$catalog->startHead('../../');
$catalog->getGetparameters();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$result4brands=mysqli_query($con,$query4brands);
$result4types=mysqli_query($con,$query4types);
$result4catalog=mysqli_query($con,$query4catalog);

$catalog->renderTitleAndMetaAndSetHeader($result);
$catalog->getGenCSS('../../');
$catalog->getGenJS('../../');
$catalog->getJS4Filters('../../');
$catalog->getCatalogJS('../../',$catalogname);
$catalog->closeHead();
$catalog->getTopBarAndStartBody('../../');
$catalog->getHeader();
$catalog->getFilters($result4brands,$result4types);
$catalog->renderProducts($result4catalog,$catalogname);
$catalog->getGetparameters();
?>
```

**UPDATES:**
I have single script in /setua/catalogues.php
everything from /setua/supplies/* is redirected to catalogues.php.
Path after supplies defines MySQL table to connect with.
In case i specify form action to

```
 $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

it redirects to URL /setua/catalogues.php so connection to required DB is lost. But then GET parameters are recognized OK. But as soon as URL /setua/supplies/* is specified in form action - GET parameters are lost

**ERROR FOUND**
If you are using $_GET it will only work from the initial page to the next page UNLESS you manually add the GET variables back into any redirects. Sounds like you are submitting your form to a page that redirects elsewhere which looses the $_GET variables.

Comment: `%5B%5D` is actually `[]` why its encoded that way? But it should work that way.

Comment: show th atcode which is generating that url

Comment: ask yourself. what would you expect `var_dump` to dump?

Comment: Added code that generating Get

Comment: Why `$get=$_GET;` before `var_dump($get);` ? What happens if you do  directly `var_dump($_GET);` ?

Comment: Just curious, why is it name="Brand[]" and not just name="Brand"?  Since it is a checkbox you can only have one value for it so is there a reason you are making it into an array?

Comment: it must have something to do with your setup. I get `array(1) { ["Brand"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "HP" } }` from `var_dump` and `Array` from `echo $_GET['Brand']`. It would be interesting to know why. But for practical reasons, you should definitely change the name from `Brand[]` to `Brand`. It is very bad practice to have special characters here. But if you could solve the encoding issue for your setup, you could to this: `$get =  $_GET['Brand'];
echo $get[0];` to get `HP`

Comment: Could you please pastebin the whole Class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think this would work: (Changed `name="Brand[]"` to `name="Brand"`)

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <h4>Brand:</h4>
    <div class="input-control checkbox">
        <label>
            <input name="Brand" type="checkbox" value="HP">
            <span class="check"></span>HP
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="bg-darkCobalt" style="box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000000; color: #ffffff"><i class="icon-list on-left fg-white"></i>Filter</button>
</form>
```

Then:

```
public function getGetparameters() {
    $get = $_GET;
    var_dump($get);  //Should get you brand => HP
};
```

---

**UPDATE**: If you have to stick with `name="Brand[]"`

*Make sure your form is going somewhere, your `action` tag being blank is odd.*

```
<form action="catalogs.php" method="get">
    <h4>Brand:</h4>
    <div class="input-control checkbox">
        <label>
            <input name="Brand[]" type="checkbox" value="Apple">
            <span class="check"></span>Apple
        </label>
        <label>
            <input name="Brand[]" type="checkbox" value="HP">
            <span class="check"></span>HP
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="bg-darkCobalt" style="box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #000000; color: #ffffff"><i class="icon-list on-left fg-white"></i>Filter</button>
</form>
```

Then, on catalogs.php:

```
public function getGetparameters() {
    $get = $_GET;
    print_r($get); 
    /* Will result with the following if only HP was checked off
    Array
    (
        [Brand] => Array
            (
                [0] => HP
            )
    )
    */
    /* Will result with the following if both checked off
    Array
    (
        [Brand] => Array
            (
                [0] => Apple
                [1] => HP
            )
    )
    */
};
```

Comment: I'd like to use this but later I will add some more brands and I need to maintain those simultaneously, so replacing Brand[] to Brand is not applicable. But I've tried and this either returned nothing. I'm totally confused

Comment: @Hunkeone but in that case, you would create a whole new checkbox, right (or radio buttons)? Because you cannot use one checkbox for multiple brands. So just rename it to `BrandHP`. And if you later add more brands, name those `BrandOtherBrand`.

Comment: rly, I didn't think of such behavior, thanks. But anyway currently this doesn't works :(

Comment: I guess you could set it to to name"brand[0]" and then check for $_GET['brand[0]'] ? And then get rid of the zero when you want to add more.

Comment: @Jason When I've entered path for form action it did work, but!
I have single script catalogues.php that renders few catalogs and <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> redirects to catalogs.php (Where Get parameters are applied correcltly!) But if I insert the same URL path it doesn't work :(
Seems solution is so close, but I cannot find it

Comment: @Jason You helped me so much, please check Updates section. Seems GET parameters are lost if they are not redirected to script itself :(
I've tried to make URL look like /setua/supplies/cartridges.php but that hadn't solved an issue

Comment: If you are using $_GET it will only work from the initial page to the next page UNLESS you manually add the GET variables back into any redirects.  Sounds like you are submitting your form to a page that redirects elsewhere which looses the $_GET variables.